# Can't enter edit mode when I have multiple armatures

Tags: armature, edit-mode, bones, pose-mode, object-mode

I've added 2 armatures. Yet when I try to edit one of them it kicks me out of Edit mode and back to Object mode. Same happens when I try to enter Pose mode. I have this problem when there's multiple armatures.

Is this some sort of bug? I remember not having this problem but can't recall when it started.

Comment: Please share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there and add the link to your question so that we can see what's going on.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you're looking for but in the top menu > Edit > Lock Object Modes?

Comment: @JohnEason


I have a recording of it happening.  Though I after this instead of using a rigify armature I did **add single bone** and created my own armature and it doesn't have the problem. (Though it did on my blend project which I found a workaround by merging them.

https://imgur.com/a/67KITDK


@ moonboots

I already have lock Object mode on. Also turning it off made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was from an addon **Rigid Body Bones**

I also disabled it and it now works.

I might go to the addon's github and report this incase someone else hasn't already.

Source : [when I try to go to edit mode or pose mode of an armature, it immediately switches back to object mode in blender 3.6](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/297328/when-i-try-to-go-to-edit-mode-or-pose-mode-of-an-armature-it-immediately-switch)